# A generic word for any 'specialized genre'

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there one? For example, "Bill was a hipster who only enjoyed [very strange and specialized genres of] music".

Comment: 'Esoteric' is an adjective that might be applicable. It usually connotes quality, though.

Comment: 'hipster' or 'alternative'

Comment: You've chosen a foreign word that no-one understands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps ***recherché***: unusual and not understood by most people (Merriam- Webster).

This word has a spectrum of meaning, from "exquisite/choice", through "affected", to "pretentious/overblown".

Would you be happy with such ambivalence? I think, from your quote, you might...?

Comment: Very cool thanks it will do nicely! *Obscure* is another good term I had overlooked but I certainly prefer recherché :)

Comment: +1 Superb choice, which you beat me to. If OP intends a dig at Bill, though, as a little over-precious, I'd suggest he refrain from italicizing this French term, lest he be hoist with his own petard.

Comment: -1. We don't need foreign words when (a) we have perfectly good words in English, and (b) the foreign word is not commonly known.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA If you don't need foreign words you might consider rephrasing your comment to omit: 'foreign', 'perfectly' and 'common', since they were all foreign words once... Even though I disagree with you, I have to say that your effort to explain the downvote is commendable, not many people do it.

Comment: @Lucky.  (a) Thank you.  (b) The comments are an important communication tool, a learning vehicle.  I use them as such. (c) I won't rephrase my comments because your points are pharisaic (if they apply, they apply only in minute ways, and in a context other than which is given).  Thus it  diffuses, rather than straightens, the focus.  I am happy to stick to EL&U on EL&U, and the context of the question.  (d) Origin, etymology are different subjects. (e) You might consider deleting irrelevant comments.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA I think only the moderators have The Power to delete any comment; I can only delete my own and none of them are irrelevant, especially those that support a good answer or disagree with the critique of a good one :-). Btw, you don't think that I wanted you to actually change your comment, do you? I was simply making a point (I'm fully aware that comments can't be edited after 5 minutes, and so are you, I believe).

Comment: @Lucky.  (a) I can only see what it written.  I have no idea about your intentions.  I would suggest, if you do not intend something, do not write it.  Otherwise, you will have respond to the consequences, and explain yourself, as you have done. (b) If you know that I know about the 5-min limit on comments, then you will know that I know who can delete them.  You don't need to explain what you know I know.  No doubt you consider doing it "relevant".

Comment: I think i made a mistake by using italics in the original post to emphasis my suggestion. I didn't intend to suggest that it be used in italics.

Comment: Recherché is an English word: its meaning is different from the French version, where it usually indicates just "sought after" (sometimes literally, when looking for, say, a lost child). That "recherché" is somewhat specialised itself was one of the reasons for choosing it, of course, in the OP's context.

Answer (score 4):

#### Obscure

I think the meaning is (a) well-known, and (b) has a wide application, so I will skip the definitions.

It is specifically applicable, given your description.  The New American Dictionary states:

> Obscure *often expresses dissatisfaction at one's inability to identify something.*

Two points:

1. genre itself is specific (or specialised<sup>1</sup>), and that you are going to give a [specific] genre is the expectation of the listener.
2. You are trying to identify a genre, but you can't.  So you want to express all that in one word.

Consider:

- Bill was a hipster who only enjoyed obscure music
- Bill was a hipster who only enjoyed *recherché* music

The foreign word is foreign, unknown, obscure (sorry).  You will have to stop and explain what it means to the other person.

#### Note

1. Your title 'specialized genre' is redundant because genre is specific. Your description is completely understood.

Answer (score 1):

As well as Margana's excellent answer, you could try *arcane*, *recondite* or *esoteric*.

Comment: Now those are just too recherché...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to all the good answers:

- pretentious
- highbrow